# How to plot the same x and y axis values as the ones of a given matplot plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I want to plot with the same x and y axis values (in a separate subplot) the errorbar that I display in the following way (the errorbar is correlated to the histogram drawn under):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
n, bin_edges, patches = ax1.hist(x, log=True, bins='doane', color='red')

bin_centres = (bin_edges[:-1] + bin_edges[1:]) / 2.
ax1.errorbar(bin_centres, n, fmt='o')

plt.xlabel("X_label")
plt.ylabel("Y_label")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Check this : [shared axis](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/shared_axis_demo.html)

Comment: Adding  fig, ax2 = plt.subplots(sharex=True, sharey=True) and  ax2.set_yscale('log') to my code (and obviously displaying the errorbar in the ax2 sublot)  worked. Thanks!